# Create a list of dataframes and use it to call details about that dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list of dataframes and then using that list of dataframes to create another dataframe about the attributes of that dataframe. I wanted to do this by creating a loop.

I tried creating a list of dataframes. Then I used that list in a loop that says for each row in my new dataframe, put in the name of the dataframe in one column and the number of rows in that dataframe in another column.

```
df_Months <- as.list(c(df_Jan2018, df_Feb2018, df_March2018, df_April2018, df_May2018))


for i in 1:length(df_Months) {
  Monthly_Size$Month[i] <- paste(df_Months [i])
  Monthly_Size$Size[i] <- nrow(df_Months[i])
}
```

if I do nrow(df_Months[1]) the result is NULL even though I know that is not the case because if i just do nrow(df_Jan2018) it gives me back the correct number of rows.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example and the expected results please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `purrr` and `dplyr` package that should work on your data. You wouldn't need the for loop anymore.

```
library("purrr")
library("dplyr") 

test_df <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                       b = c(NA,6,5,7,9))

test_df2 <- data.frame(c = c(1:10),
                       d = c(11:20))

df_list <- list(test_df = test_df, test_df2 = test_df2)

res <- map_dbl(df_list,nrow)
tibble(df = names(res), nrow = res)
```

The output looks like this

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  df        nrow
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 test_df      5
2 test_df2    10
```

A slightly different approach would be to put the above list `df_list` into a tibble and then do operations on that tibble and create new rows with the information you are looking for.

```
df_tibble <- tibble(name = names(df_list), df = df_list)

df_tibble %>% mutate(nrow = map_dbl(df, ~ nrow(.x)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name     df                     nrow
  <chr>    <list>                <dbl>
1 test_df  <data.frame [5 × 2]>      5
2 test_df2 <data.frame [10 × 2]>    10
```

You could go on and include more information in this way. For example the number of columns.

```
df_tibble %>% mutate(nrow = map_dbl(df, ~ nrow(.x)),
                     ncol = map_dbl(df, ~ ncol(.x)))
```